# Conflict with multiple Symfony projects when OpCache enabled

Tags: php, linux, symfony, server, opcache

I have a problem with multiple Symfony projects on php server (with PHP-FPM) when `OpCache` is enabled. One of projects tries to access files from the other one.

```
File(/var/www/clients/client101/web133/vendor/composer/../../src/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/dev/urandom:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/src:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/bin:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/app:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/var:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/vendor:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/web:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/private:/var/www/clients/client85/web110/tmp:/var/www/[domain]/web:/srv/www/[domain]/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin)
in /var/www/clients/client101/web133/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 364
```

Please note the difference between paths (`client101/web133` and `client85/web110`). The problem does not appear when `OpCache` is disabled.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue. Two installs of symfony, but when opcache is enabled they try and access each other's files. Did you make any progress on this issue?

Comment: @menko Unfortunately, nope :( I don't even work in that place anymore.